# Returning output of bash script to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I'm playing around with what should be a simple script.
I've got a bash script one line that just runs an API call to a server I have.
I've got a py3 script that calls that bash script in a function and returns the output.

I'm then setting a variable equal to the function, and finally printing that variable.

For some reason even though im not directly calling the function (I guess I am when im declaring my variable) it's running the function anyway, and my variable's value is set to 0.

I've tried it a couple different ways and set it up similar to how some of the posts on here have said but I just dont understand why it's doing this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess


def api_call():
    return subprocess.call("/home/gposcl1/PyNetBox/api_GET.sh")
    
print("")
print("")
print("")

api_call_result = api_call()

print("")
print("")
print("")

print(api_call_result)
```

This is the output I'm getting. I've changed the output of the API call as it's rather unimportant to the question and contains sensitive data:

> $
> $ ./var1.py
> {"count":3,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"id":31689,"url":,"role":null,"is_pool":false,"description":"1234_lower","tags":[],"custom_fields":{},"created":"2021-02-05","last_updated":"2021-02-05T06:20:16.733088Z"}]}
> 0
> $

Comment: check this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: That post solved it, ty sir!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `run` instead of `call`, you can set `capture_output` to `True` and then retrieve `stdout`:

```
def api_call():
    r = subprocess.run("/home/gposcl1/PyNetBox/api_GET.sh", capture_output=True)
    return r.stdout.decode()
```

Comment: I'm on py3.6 so this wont work for me but maybe my admin will upgrade me.

Comment: Are you sure ? Documentation for 3.6 says _"The run() function was added in Python 3.5;"_.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's the `capture_output` that's missing

Comment: Tyr replacing `capture_output=True` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess


def api_call():
    r = subprocess.run("/home/gposcl1/PyNetBox/api_GET.sh", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return r.stdout


print("")
print("")
print("")

api_call_result = api_call()

print("")
print("")
print("")

print(api_call_result)
```